# Not able to process Ajax Request in Code ignitor1.7.3

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Following of my code which is working fine in code ignitor 1.7.1 now not able to invoke controller method **user/checkAvailability?requestSource=USER_AVAILABILITY** it goves to error block and printing alert as alert('In side Error');

I found that none of Jquery Ajax request not working ..

not able to understand why its not going to call controller method,

Please help

```
function checkAvailability(){   $.blockUI({message: null}); 
    var newMessage = 'E1';
    $('#searchLoading').show();     alert('I am here');     $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "user/checkAvailability?requestSource=USER_AVAILABILITY",
                cache: false,               
                data: "userName=" + $("#userName").val(),
                success: function(json){
                    alert("Printing Json");
                    try{
                        $.unblockUI();                  
                        var obj = JSON.parse(json);                                         

                        if(obj[0].STATUS=='true'){                                                
                            newMessage = "E15";
                            $('#checkUser').hide();                          
                        }else{
                            newMessage = "E16";                     
                            $("#checkUser").hide();                    
                        }                   
                        showMessage(newMessage);
                        $('#searchLoading').hide();
                    }catch(e) {     
                            alert('In side Exception');
                            showMessage("E1");  
                            $.unblockUI();  
                            $('#searchLoading').hide();
                    }       
                },
                error: function(){

                    alert('In side Error');
                    $('#searchLoading').hide();
                    $.unblockUI();                  
                    $("#checkUser").hide();                     
                    showMessage(newMessage);        
                    $( "form" )[0].reset();

                }        });
          }
```

CI Method in controller User

```
/**
        This method is used to check User Name availabiliy.
    */

    public function checkAvailability(){    

        $userName = trim($this->input->post('userName'));

        $query = $this->UserModel->getUser($userName);  

        $status =array("STATUS"=>"true");   

        if($query){
            $status = array("STATUS"=>"false");
        }

        echo json_encode (array($status)) ; 
    }
```

Comment: Heard of FirePHP? http://www.firephp.org/ It should help you debug a bit... Try commenting out everything and just calling `echo json_encode(array("STATUS"=>"true"));` Your code seems pretty straight-forward but something funky could be going on.

Comment: @Fred- Server part and response comes later my problem i am not able to post ajax request to controller. look my java script function

Comment: Frieds -- found issue after some R&D, issue is related to URL user/checkAvailability?requestSource=USER_AVAILABILITY when i remove ?requestSource=USER_AVAILABILITY from URL its works , i thought its because of GET kind of URL, because i mention method type as POST in ajax request, please provide comment if you have any other views thanks Yashwant

Answer (score 1):

The error usually appears when the AJAX request doesn't reach the page.

Change the URL in your AJAX request to an absolute path i.e.

`url: "/user/checkAvailability?requestSource=USER_AVAILABILITY"`

or

`url: "http://site.com/user/checkAvailability?requestSource=USER_AVAILABILITY"`

Comment: Hi tried with this but still there is problem http://localhost/businesscaliber/index.php/user/checkAvailability?requestSource=USER_AVAILABILITY

Answer (score 1):

The largest cause of problems for people upgrading to 1.7.3 is that they override their config files. Make sure ALL config files are backed up before hand, or reverted to afterward.

Sod all changed in 1.7.3 apart from a security hotfix on one line of code, which would not break AJAX.

Comment: Also, this is AJAX so use Firebug to debug it. You'll find out the error instantly if you look at the response.

Comment: Is there is any configuration required for Ajax ? Also i tried with firebug none of the error found.

Comment: What is the response showing for the request of this AJAX call? Are you looking at the Console tab? Do you know how AJAX and Firebug work? :)

Comment: @Phil in my java script function checkAvailability().. I not able to send request to controller before that it breaks and goes to error: function(){
}  function , So without sending request how will i get response, my problem is not able to send ajax request to controller...

Comment: There is an error in your JavaScript somewhere, debug it... I cannot tell from here, especially without an error message.

Comment: Frieds -- found issue after some R&D, issue is related to URL user/checkAvailability?requestSource=USER_AVAILABILITY when i remove ?requestSource=USER_AVAILABILITY from URL its works , i thought its because of GET kind of URL, because i mention method type as POST in ajax request, please provide comment if you have any other views thanks Yashwant –

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also try explicitly setting the dataType property to json when making the AJAX request in JQuery.  It could be that JQuery is trying to parse the JSON as something else.

```
dataType:'json'
```

More info here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And I'd echo Phil's advice to use either Firebug or the developer console in Chrome to find out whats happening your AJAX request.

Comment: JSON comes picture later when there is a response. but my problem is i am not able to process Ajax Request

Comment: I see. My mistake. You are deserialising the JSON in your callback function. I thought you were using JQuery's own in-built JSON deserialisation. Nevermind. Carry on! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have querystrings enabled in your config.php

should be around line 151 of system/application/config/config.php

change

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

to

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

I'm assuming there is a reason you have ?requestSource=USER_AVAILABILITY tagged on the url.

Also yes, use the complete url (including http://) in your ajax url.